# Kali vmware live vs graphic install

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I was following [Kali VM installations](http://www.drchaos.com/the-ultimate-installation-guide-for-kali-linux/) and trying to create a Kali virtual machine with VMWare. So far, Everything is ok. And I can do everything in the `Live` without installation when the VM start up. So I want to know in what case we need install the Kali?

[image]

Comment: I just installed Kali Linux 2 Sana in VMware Workstation 11 by doing the steps in this article: [How to Install Kali Linux 2 Sana in VMware Workstation 11 Step-by-Step Guide](http://www.sysadminshowto.com/how-to-install-kali-linux-2-sana-in-vmware-workstation-11-step-by-step-guide/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want to do an install if you want to make sure your VM stays up to date, or if you want to install any tools that aren't on the ISO. For me, I write a lot of scripts, and prefer a full linux box, or VM so i can make sure the plethora of scripts i end up writing stay permanent.

There are advantages to not installing too, like the fact that if you hork something up, a fresh instance is a reboot away.

Comment: Does it mean you can't install anything or make any change to the virtual machine in the Live? thanks.

Comment: Usually if you're setup to use the ISO, you can't make changes running live. I think there's a way to trick it into thinking you're on USB, but an install is better